# nth-child() and blockquote css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this html code

```
<blockquote>
    <cite>oioik wrote:</cite>

    <blockquote>
            <cite>oioik wrote:</cite>

            <blockquote>
                <cite>oioik wrote:</cite>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
            </blockquote>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
    </blockquote>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
</blockquote>
```

and I have this css

```
blockquote {
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 0;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
blockquote:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then in my example I should have blue/red/blue background colors but I have blue/red/red

Comment: that's because your blockquotes are nested

Comment: even is related to the position compared to the siblings

Comment: you like this http://jsfiddle.net/V59Cq/1/

Comment: I know they're nested thats why I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between *child* and *descendant*.

So if you had:

```
 <blockquote>1</blockquote>
 <blockquote>2</blockquote>
 <blockquote>3</blockquote>
```

They are all children of the same parent, numbered as shown.

The second pair are red because they're both the second child of their respective parents (the first being the `<cite>` element.)

In this case, I don't believe vanilla CSS will achieve what you want to do. You may have to inject a class name to do this.